# Rotate around an object to its direction of velocity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, orbital-mechanics

(For Unity 5.3.5f1)
Right now I am working on a 3D camera that is orbiting horizontally around the player. The player is a RigidBody rolling sphere. The player can freely rotate the axis horizontally but when there is no input I want the rotation to reset back to the direction of the velocity.

Right now all I need to know is how to situate the camera behind the player's direction of velocity by rotating the camera around the player from its previous rotation.

Here is a crude drawing of what I am looking for:
[image]

Currently to update the camera to orbit around the player I use this script on the camera (with comments):

```
 using UnityEngine;
 using System.Collections;

 public class example : MonoBehaviour {

     public GameObject Player;
     //I assume you would use this PlayerRB to find data regarding the movement or velocity of the player.
     //public Rigidbody PlayerRB;

     private float moveHorizontalCamera;
     private Vector3 offset;

     // Use this for initialization
     void Start ()
     {   //the offset of the camera to the player
         offset = new Vector3(Player.transform.position.x - transform.position.x,  transform.position.y - Player.transform.position.y, transform.position.z - Player.transform.position.z);
     }

     // Update is called once per frame
     void Update ()
     {
         moveHorizontalCamera = Input.GetAxis("Joy X"); //"Joy X" is my right joystick moving left, none, or right resulting in -1, 0, or 1 respectively

         //Copied this part from the web, so I half understand what it does.
         offset = Quaternion.AngleAxis(moveHorizontalCamera, Vector3.up) * offset;
         transform.position = Player.transform.position + offset;
         transform.LookAt(Player.transform.position);
     }
 }
```

Any help at all would be great!

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Q1xZGt41N80

Comment: to explain the last 3 lines of you code (as you say you only understand it partly): the line with `Quaternion.AngleAxis * offset` rotates the vector offset by moveHorizontalCamera degree around the y-axis. the next line translates the transforms position to playerposition + offset (the rotated offset vector) and the last line rotates the transform such that transform.forward is pointing toward the player

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you use `Vector3.RotateTowards` (https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector3.RotateTowards.html)

You take the Vector that is currently pointing from the Player to the camera (`transform.position - Player.transform.position`) and rotate it towards `-Player.GetComponent<Rigidbody>().velocity.normalized * desiredDistance` (the vector pointing in the opposite direction of the players velocity with magnitude corresponding the desired distance of the camera to the player). You can then use `Vector3.RotateTowards` to rotate the camera (smoothly or immediately) around the Player by setting the cameras position accordingly.

Something like:

```
transform.position = Player.transform.position + Vector3.RotateTowards(transform.position - Player.transform.position, -Player.GetComponent<Rigidbody>().velocity.normalized * desiredDistance, step, .0f);
```

where step if the angle update in radians. (Note: you should avoid calling `GetComponent<Rigidbody>()` every Update. You are better off storing it somewhere)

I hope I understood your question correctly and this helps.

Comment: This is great! But is there anyway I could set the desiredDistance to my original offset and my original rotation? I also need it locked on the y-axis, not rotating above or below the player, only around it as like a 2d circular motion. Update of my code so far, I think I am using it right (@ line 45): (http://pastebin.com/b30HXdXB). I also desire acceleration but I think that is already enough for one comment.

Comment: to set the desiredDistance to your original offsets distance just set its value to `desiredDistance = offset.magnitude`. you can lock the cameras y-position to the players y-position just by setting it equal after rotating: `transform.position.y = Player.transform.position.y` (although this should not be necessary as long as the players velocity is parallel to the y-axis)